# Get all checkboxes under a given dom element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, let me admit I haven't used jquery very much.

I know I can get all checkboxes under a div with the id #mydiv by using

```
var boxes = $('#mydiv input[type*=checkbox]');
```

but what if this is in an external script and I pass in the id? Can I do something like

```
function myFunct(divId)
{
var boxes = $('#' + divId + ' input[type*=checkbox]');
// do something to the boxes here
}
```

or is there a way that I can create the jquery object for the div by $('#myDiv')and find the checkboxes under that?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out ? :) The function you have there would work fine.

Comment: Your code will work.

Comment: is this a demo because it think nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work OK. When I was typing the question, I wanted to get as close as possible to right.

Answer (score 1):

This will check all checkboxes if they have a class `mydiv`:

```
$(".mydiv  input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = [];
$('#mydiv input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

or

```
var selected = [];
$('div#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
   }
});
```